# Redirect all incoming traffic

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, httpd, rhel6

I have a RHEL6.4 httpd VirtualHost that I want to use to forward inbound traffic like so:

```
Any incorrect host names in requests will redirected correctly to my SERVER_NAME
```

AND

```
Any non-port-443 traffic will be redirected to https:// correctly
```

By correctly, I meant that any part of the URL submitted after the hostname will be preserved. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

First, define your correct https vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  whatever.example.com
    # everything else
</VirtualHost>
```

Now define your HTTP to HTTP redirect:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  whatever.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://whatever.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

And now, define a catchall host for redirecting the incorrect ones:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  catchall.example.com
    ServerAlias *
    Redirect permanent / https://whatever.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

[Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) will preserve your parameters and paths.

Comment: This seems to be what the OP is asking for. She might want to read up on SNI and in mod_rewrite about specific business rules that need to be applied